# How to filter displaying widget per categories

Tags: flutter

I have a list of categories in categories Models:

```
class Categories {
  final int id;
  final String categoryName;
  final String categoryImage;
  final String categorySubTitle;
  final String categoryDescription;

  Categories({
    this.id,
    this.categoryName,
    this.categoryImage,
    this.categorySubTitle,
    this.categoryDescription
  });
}

List<Categories> categories = [tarocchi, amore, cartomanzia, viaggi, salute,carriera];
```

this list create a Listview:

```
return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          itemCount: categories.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => ConsultantListScreen(
                       
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

each Categories Item has a Gesture detector which should move to another screen where User subscribed to a specific categories should be displayed.

so How I can define into the 2 screen that only the user with the selected categories will be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to solve this.

An easy way is to create the 2nd screen with a filter argument: `ConsultantListScreen(categoryID)` and then use it in its build method:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
...
var usersSubscribed = allUsers.where((u) => u.isSubscribedToCategory(categoryID));  // this information will probably come from a Provider, or maybe from a global index or something :-)
...
}
```

Personally, I think it would be more elegant if a switch to a second page wasn't necessary at all. E.g. you could create filter buttons or tags from the categories and simply filter the users by them. But that's your design decision, of course.

Comment: Ok it is also a good way to create a filter button slide above the list but how to create this filter?
For example I can create a horizontal List with all the categories and when user clicks on the category the widget change with only the user with the categoires selected but how to do it?

Comment: Again, there's many ways to achieve this, and it's your design decision. :-)

I like [ExpansionTiles](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html), or it's also quite easy with flutter to create filtered lists (there's even a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/filter_list) for it, if you like). Search for it on google, there's many tutorials and videos on how to do it.